# не выводит данные по ip пользователя

Tags: php

```
$ip = '83.149.47.116'; // IP, который будем проверять
$typeData = 'json'; // в каком виде мы получим данные. json или xml

// формируем URL для запроса
$url = "http://ru.smart-ip.net/geoip-$typeData/$ip";
// делаем запрос к API
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
// если получили данные
if($data){
// декодируем полученные данные
$dataDecode = json_decode($data);

// выводим данные
echo "Страна: " . $dataDecode->countryName . "<br/>";
echo "Код страны: " . $dataDecode->countryCode . "<br/>";
echo "Город: " . $dataDecode->city . "<br/>";
echo "Область: " . $dataDecode->region . "<br/>";
echo "Широта: " . $dataDecode->latitude . "<br/>";
echo "Долгота: " . $dataDecode->longitude . "<br/>";
echo "Часовой пояс: " . $dataDecode->timezone . "<br/>";

}else{
echo "Сервер не доступен!";
}
```

Выводит на Экран:

```
Страна:
Код страны:
Город:
Область:
Широта:
Долгота:
Часовой пояс:
```

Логи апача:

```
[Tue Apr 18 11:19:10.388594 2017] [:error] [pid 3581] [client 127.0.0.1:35456] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/projects/geoip.com/index.php on line 16
...
[Tue Apr 18 11:19:10.388643 2017] [:error] [pid 3581] [client 127.0.0.1:35456] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/projects/geoip.com/index.php on line 22
```

Comment: а вы хоть пробовали вывести  и проверить что находится в переменой $dataDecode ??  например print_r($dataDecode);

Comment: у вас же в логах пишет "Trying to get property of non-object in " т.е возможно переменная просто пуста

Comment: @Arsen читать логи и тексты ошибок - для слабаков! Настоящие мужики пишут на SO!

Comment: Arsen, выводил конечно, print_r($dataDecode); - и ничего нет на экране. По логике $dataDecode заносятся данные из $data, а $data d в свою очередь берет из $ip, и сверяет ее с базой geoip, где и берет все данные об этом адресе, которые в коде и должен вывести.но логи апача написано, что не получилось взять свойства несуществующего объекта...т.е. либо такого ip не существует, либо что-то в коде не так....

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за Ваш комментарий! Очень "полезный"!

Comment: `print_r($dataDecode); - и ничего нет на экране` - ну так, а что же вы ожидали увидеть в результате обращения к пустой переменной? логично что будет `Trying to get property of non-object` .......а вот если бы вы еще специально не глушили ошибки, возникающие  в процессе (я намекаю на `@file_get_contents` и конкретно на собачку `@`) - то можно было увидеть это всё еще раньше

Comment: Алексей, я НЕ волшебник, я только учусь!)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский собачка там ни на что не влияет - вывод будет ровно такой же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы проверите в вашем коде переменную `$data`, то обнаружите, что вы не получаете какой-либо массив данных, вместо этого вы получаете `Service Temporaly Unavailable`. Собственно, если зайти по адресу `http://ru.smart-ip.net/geoip-json/83.149.47.116`, итог будет таким же. Соответственно, ваш код в дальнейшем получает из `json_decode($data);` `$dataDecode=NULL`, ну и дальше все понятно.

Проблема с этим сервисом общая, не только у вас. Будет он в дальнейшем работать или нет - вопрос к его создателям. Пока что же у них не работает их API в принципе, ни в формате `json`, ни в формате `xml`.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, сервис, с которым стоит работать?

Comment: @Александр вот насчет этого не подскажу, к сожалению. Попробуйте создать на этот счет отдельный вопрос на сервисе, ну или поискать самостоятельно.

Comment: Станислав, я нашел сервис, который работает точно, но на определенных правах (мне они для моих целей не мешают)
$url = "http://api.2ip.ua/geo.json?ip=";